# How to get rid of a huge local Docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

*Caveat*: I'm new to Docker user

I pulled a docker image to my machine:

```
sudo docker pull docker.local:5000/rhel7/24_GB_docker_image
```

This image is 24GB in size, and I'd like to delete it from my machine, without deleting it from docker.local machine.

Are there documents/URLs that would point me in the correct direction to achieve the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `docker rmi`. It deletes a local image (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi)

```
# find the image ID
docker images --filter reference=docker.local:5000/rhel7/24_GB_docker_image

# delete image
docker rmi <image ID>
```

Answer (score 1):

To clean up not used images, containers, etc. you can use the `docker system prune` command.Itwill ask you what you want to delete.